# Kafka Connect - Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: PK mode for table is RECORD_KEY, but record key schema is missing

Tags: oracle, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have jdbc-sink for transfer data from Kafka to Oracle Database.

**My connect gives this error.**

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: PK mode for table 'orders' is RECORD_KEY, but record key schema is missing
```

**my sink properties :**

```
{
  "name": "jdbc-oracle",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "orders",
    "connection.url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.1.2.3:1071/orac",
    "connection.user": "ersin",
    "connection.password": "ersin!",
    "auto.create": "true",
    "delete.enabled": "true",
    "pk.mode": "record_key",
    "pk.fields": "MESSAGE_KEY",
    "insert.mode": "update ",
    "plugin.path": "/home/ersin/confluent-5.4.1/share/java/",
    "name": "jdbc-oracle"
  },
  "tasks": [
    {
      "connector": "jdbc-oracle",
      "task": 0
    }
  ],
  "type": "sink"
}
```

**my connect-avro-distributed.properties**   :

```
bootstrap.servers=10.0.0.0:9092

group.id=connect-cluster

key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://10.0.0.0:8081
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=http://10.0.0.0:8081

config.storage.topic=connect-configs
offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets
status.storage.topic=connect-statuses

config.storage.replication.factor=1
offset.storage.replication.factor=1
status.storage.replication.factor=1

internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
```

**I send data like this:**

```
./bin/kafka-avro-console-producer \
--broker-list 10.0.0.0:9092 --topic orders \
--property parse.key="true" \
--property key.schema='{"type":"record","name":"key_schema","fields":[{"name":"id","type":"int"}]}' \
--property key.separator="$" \
--property value.schema='{"type":"record","name":"myrecord","fields":[{"name":"id","type":"int"},{"name":"product","type":"string"}, {"name":"quantity", "type": "int"}, {"name":"price","type": "int"}]}' \
--property schema.registry.url=http://10.0.0.0:8081
```

How can I solve this?

thanks in advance

Comment: Share your kafka connect configuration too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be with your payload and the configuration `"pk.mode": "record_key"`.

`pk.mode` is used to define the primary key mode and you have the following config options:

- `none`: No keys utilized
- `kafka`: Kafka coordinates are used as the PK
- `record_key`: Field(s) from the record key are used, which may be a primitive or a struct.
- `record_value`: Field(s) from the record value are used, which must be a struct.

---

In your configuration, you are using `record_key` which means that Kafka Connect will take the field from the key of the message and use it as the primary key in the target Oracle table.

Although you haven't shared your Kafka Connect worker's configuration, my guess is that you are missing some configuration parameters in there.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/3.1.1/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/sink_connector.html),

> The sink connector requires knowledge of schemas, so you should use a
>   suitable converter e.g. the Avro converter that comes with the schema
>   registry, or the JSON converter with schemas enabled. Kafka record
>   keys if present can be primitive types or a Connect struct, and the
>   record value must be a Connect struct. Fields being selected from
>   Connect structs must be of primitive types. If the data in the topic
>   is not of a compatible format, implementing a custom `Converter` may
>   be necessary.

---

Now in your case the problem seems to be `"pk.fields"` which is currently set to `"pk.fields": "MESSAGE_KEY"`. In your schema, the message key is defined to be `id`. Therefore, the following should do the trick:

```
"pk.fields": "id"
```

Comment: json data I try  like this : {"id":1}${"id": 1, "product": "Yağız Gülbahar", "quantity": 1453, "price": 1453}

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar Update your question and include your connect configuration.;

Comment: what you mean by sayin connect confugaration , I already put my oracle sink properties

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#connect-configuring-workers

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar Also, In your real config is this `"pk.fields": "MESSAGE_KEY"` actually `"pk.fields": "id"` ?

Comment: yes this is the solution :) thanks  "pk.fields": "id"